# ejabberd rest API without authentication, 403 Forbidden (error code 32)

Tags: rest, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I'm trying to access ejabberd rest api without authentication but always get a `403 Forbidden` response with this body :

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "code": 32,
    "message": "AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation."
}
```

I cannot get an OK response on `/api/status` endpoint which is a command that all users from 127.0.0.1 should be able to use (see "public commands" section under `api_permissions` in ejabberd.yml).

Here's the request details (via Insomnia REST client):

```
> POST /api/status HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: insomnia/5.1.0
> Host: localhost:5280
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 2
| {}
```

Ejabberd version is 17.04, installed from a downloaded deb package and running on Debian 8.8 (jessie) x86_64 as `ejabberd` user.
Post install, I simply added the host "localhost", registered a new user "admin" for localhost and added it to the ACLs.

The only changes I made into ejabberd.yml :

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "localhost"
```

Otherwise, I can access the webadmin interface which works fine...
What can I do in order to have a 200 OK response ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. Like the message said it was a permission issue.
Here's the default configuration :

```
api_permissions:
## ...
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
```

This **does not** allow to access to `status` or `connected_users_number` commands **with or without authentication** (I triple-checked).

For a no authentication usage, use `-all` :

```
  "public commands":
    who:
## This allows to use both commands without having to authenticate
      - all
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
```

If you want to require a valid user (with basic authentication), replace `- all` by `- access: local`.

```
  "public commands":
    who:
## This allows to use both commands with basic authentication for local users
      - access: local
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, how could I also enforce ip restriction?

Comment: What version are you using ? In 17.04, it was not working with - ip: "127.0.0.1/8" for me.
But in later versions it seems to works fine.